# How to turn a 2D array in to grids

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to python and I am currently working on a project which will involve mapping an indoor environment. I hope to create a function which will take in sensory data and turn it into a simple map like this:

```
maps = [------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |                                                                
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |                                                                |
        |-----------------------------------------------------------------]
```

How then would I go about changing this array into a labelled grid based system, where the top left grid would be A-1 and the bottom right grid E-5?

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? How to label it? What does the data actually look like? List of strings? List of lists of something?

Comment: I am asking is there a method or function that achieves what I am asking for. The data will be an array map like the one above that is composed of strings to signify the objects found in the environment. How do I turn this array into a grid based system like the one I described?

Comment: What is an "array map" in python terms? Are you using a third party module? Editing the above to be valid python code that generates sample data would be helpful.

Comment: I meant an array, map which is structured in the way I laid out in my initial question. I do not have code to generate this data as I am currently waiting on the components needed to collect said data, but I will hope to generate it in a manner like that in my question

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps can I suggest [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which will help you to focus on strategy.

A generic random example :

```
themap=pd.DataFrame(take(list('   xo'),randint(0,5,(10,10))),\
arange(10)+1,list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

In [268]: themap
Out[268]: 
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
1         x  o                 x
2      o        o  x  x  x      
3   x        x  o           o   
4               o           x   
5   o  o  x  o  o           x   
6   o  o     x                 o
7   o     x           x        o
8               o  o     o      
9   x     x     o           o  x
10  o  x           x     x  o
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this method and instead of having the 'x' have the part of the map that this grid refers to? So A1 is the top left hand of the map?

Comment: Of course.  What do you mean by *the part of the map that this grid refers to* ?

Comment: So that A1 displays the top left-hand side of the array, E5 is the bottom right-hand side and the rest are the in betweens. I'm sorry I'm not sure how else to word this?

Comment: I can understand your underlying data.  an image ? a matrix of number ?  what is an indoor environnement ?

Comment: The mock data I provided is simply the outline of a room, or basically its walls represented as an array containing the characters '|' and '-'. Then from this point I hope to fill the rest of the room in with characters like 'o' and 'x' to represent any objects that may be found inside the room. I suppose this could be instead represented as a matrix of numbers